# How to display all entries from my mongodb atlas database using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

This is my current code to find all entries from MongoDB atlas.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const client = new MongoClient(url);
const dbName = "Chats";
const db = client.db(dbName);
const col = db.collection("Users");

app.post('/chat/enter', (req, res) => {
  let newmsg = new DataClass(req.body.name, req.body.textChat);
  add(newmsg).catch(console.dir);
  res.render(path.join(__dirname + "/index.ejs"),{texts:texts});
})

async function add(x) {
    try{
         await client.connect();
         await col.insertOne({"name":x.name,"textChat":x.msg});
    }catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
    }
}

async function find(){
  try{
    await client.connect();
    const a= await col.find({});
    console.log(a);
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}

find();
```

I want to display all the entries from my atlas database but so far I am getting this gibberish. This problem only arises when I use the find keyword or the output is more than one. findOne is working properly.

The output from the terminal is -

```js
FindCursor {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(topology)]: Topology {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      topologyDescriptionChanged: [Array],
      connectionPoolCreated: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionPoolClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCreated: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionReady: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckOutStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckOutFailed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckedOut: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckedIn: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionPoolCleared: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandSucceeded: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandFailed: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverOpening: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverDescriptionChanged: [Function (anonymous)],
      topologyOpening: [Function (anonymous)],
      topologyClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      close: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 25,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    bson: [Object: null prototype] {
      serialize: [Function: serialize],
      deserialize: [Function: deserialize]
    },
    s: {
      id: 0,
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      seedlist: [Array],
      state: 'connected',
      description: [TopologyDescription],
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      servers: [Map],
      sessionPool: [ServerSessionPool],
      sessions: Set(0) {},
      credentials: [MongoCredentials],
      clusterTime: [Object],
      connectionTimers: Set(0) {},
      detectShardedTopology: [Function: detectShardedTopology],
      detectSrvRecords: [Function: detectSrvRecords],
      srvPoller: [SrvPoller]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(waitQueue)]: Denque {
      _head: 3,
      _tail: 3,
      _capacity: undefined,
      _capacityMask: 3,
      _list: [Array]
    }
  },
  [Symbol(namespace)]: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'Chats', collection: 'Users' },
  [Symbol(documents)]: [],
  [Symbol(initialized)]: false,
  [Symbol(closed)]: false,
  [Symbol(killed)]: false,
  [Symbol(options)]: {
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    raw: false,
    enableUtf8Validation: true
  },
  [Symbol(filter)]: {},
  [Symbol(builtOptions)]: {
    raw: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    enableUtf8Validation: true,
    writeConcern: WriteConcern { w: 'majority' },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try adding a `next()` function to the _find_ function.  `const a= await col.find({}).next()`

Answer (score 0):

use toArray()

> const a= await col.find({}).toArray()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).